# Split string by number of character in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am looking to split string at 70 character and I found below code from this [link](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=substr-dynamically-spliting-the-string) which is slightly different than I am looking. Below code is splitting character at the max of 70 using the last space as break but what I am looking is without the last space as break. I tried to make changes from this code but honestly I am still learning the regexp_substr function and unable to figure out where the last space is considered. It will be very helpful if someone guide me through this. Thanks

Code:

```
with val as ( 
  select 'I am also looking for similar solution but slightly different where the split occurs at 70 character and not considering last space.' str
  from dual
), words as (
  select regexp_substr(str, '[^ ]+', 1, level) w
  from val
  connect by regexp_substr(str, '[^ ]+', 1, level) is not null
), grps as (
  select * from words 
  match_recognize (
    measures 
      match_number () grp,
      count ( text.* ) word#
    all rows per match
    pattern ( init text* )
    define 
      text as sum ( length ( w ) ) + count ( text.* ) <= 70
  )
)
  select listagg ( w, ' ' ) 
           within group ( order by word# ) split_strs
  from   grps
  group  by grp
  order  by grp;
```

Result from above code:
[image]

What I am looking to achieve is,
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need a Hierarchical query containing `SUBSTR()` function such as

```
 SELECT level-1 AS "Row_Number",
        SUBSTR(str,70*(level-1)+1,70*level)
   FROM val
CONNECT BY level <= CEIL(LENGTH(str)/70)
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=fd770718237074e018a1aadcc7bd044c)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, I got almost I am looking with the below code except failing for longer text than the example I gave. I will posted here if I can make this work. <br> `with val as ( 
  select 'I am also looking for similar solution but slightly different where the split occurs at 70 character and not considering last space.' str
  from dual
)
SELECT SUBSTR(str,70*(level-1)+1,70*level) str
   FROM val
CONNECT BY level <= CEIL(LENGTH(str)/70)`

Answer (score 0):

For exactly 70 chars you can use `SUBSTR` instead of `regexp_substr`.

e.g. first 70 chars = `SUBSTR(val,1,70)`

Comment: This gives only the first 70 character though, how can this can be used to split further at every 70 character into multiple rows?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice your comment yesterday and some nice people (@Barbaros) have already provided the full solution :)

Answer (score 0):

This one done the trick, thanks those responded before I get to this.

```
with val as ( 
  select 'I am also looking for similar solution but slightly different where the split occurs at 70 character and not considering last space.' str
  from dual
), words as (
  select regexp_substr(str, '(.{1})', 1, level) w
  from val
  connect by regexp_substr(str, '(.{1})', 1, level) is not null
), grps as (
  select * from words 
  match_recognize (
    measures 
      match_number () grp,
      count ( text.* ) word#
    all rows per match
    pattern ( init text* )
    define 
      text as sum ( length ( w ) ) <= 70
  )
)
  select listagg ( w, '' ) 
           within group ( order by word# ) split_strs
  from   grps
  group  by grp
  order  by grp
;
```